# How do I fix the formatting of my print statement after it gets messed up when an integer output goes over "9"?

Tags: java, formatting

For the sake of not flooding my question with code, I coded a snippet that reproduces the same issue as the original code. As the title states, the print statement for my scoreboard gets messed up after one of the integers (specifically the `aiScore`) goes over 9. How would I go about fixing this? Is there a better way which I should format my print statement? I've provided a photo before and after `aiScore` goes over 9.

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      int playerScore = 0;
      int aiScore = 10;
      int ties = 0;
      int gamesPlayed = 0;
      System.out.println("\tPlayer Wins" + "\t   CPU Wins" + "\t     Ties" + "\t Games Played");
      System.out.println("\t     " + playerScore + "\t\t      " + aiScore + "\t\t       " + ties + "\t      " + gamesPlayed);
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use all that concatenation, use [formatted print](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)).

```
System.out.printf("    %10s %10s %10s%n", "heading1", "heading2", "heading3");
System.out.printf("    %10d %10d %10d%n", num1, num2, num3);
```

In this example I happen to have 3 numeric values to print in columns, and I happen to believe 10 characters is wide enough.

Adjust according to your needs.

%s is a general string field. %d is a decimal integer.  %n is a newline (this one does not take a value from the argument list).

[Documentation for format string here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html).

Formatters show up in various places. There's "printf" as shown, the String.format method, and so on.